# how to upload a recorded audio file using pdo to the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

folks! I'm trying to implement an audio recorder within my website. What I want is to make the user save the recorded file directly to the database and to a subfolder in my website (called /speaking_audios). There follows the main files:

recorder.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FlashWavRecorder demo</title>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/recorder.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1><a href="https://github.com/cykod/FlashWavRecorder">FlashWavRecorder</a></h1>
    <p><strong>Upload requires php, i.e. example will not work on github.com</strong></p>


    <div id="recorder-audio" class="control_panel idle">
      <button class="record_button" onclick="FWRecorder.record('audio', 'audio.wav');" title="Record">
        <img src="images/record.png" alt="Record"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_recording_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopRecording('audio');" title="Stop Recording">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Recording"/>
      </button>
      <button class="play_button" onclick="FWRecorder.playBack('audio');" title="Play">
          <img src="images/play.png" alt="Play"/>
      </button>
      <button class="pause_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.pausePlayBack('audio');" title="Pause Playing">
          <img src="images/pause.png" alt="Pause Playing"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopPlayBack();" title="Stop Playing">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Playing"/>
      </button>
      <div class="level"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="recorder-audio2" class="control_panel idle">
      <button class="record_button" onclick="FWRecorder.record('audio2', 'audio2.wav');" title="Record">
        <img src="images/record.png" alt="Record"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_recording_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopRecording('audio2');" title="Stop Recording">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Recording"/>
      </button>
      <button class="play_button" onclick="FWRecorder.playBack('audio2');" title="Play">
        <img src="images/play.png" alt="Play"/>
      </button>
      <button class="pause_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.pausePlayBack('audio2');" title="Pause Playing">
        <img src="images/pause.png" alt="Pause Playing"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopPlayBack();" title="Stop Playing">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Playing"/>
      </button>
      <div class="level"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="details">
      <button class="show_level" onclick="FWRecorder.observeLevel();">Show Level</button>
      <button class="hide_level" onclick="FWRecorder.stopObservingLevel();" style="display: none;">Hide Level</button>
      <span id="save_button">
        <span id="flashcontent">
          <p>Your browser must have JavaScript enabled and the Adobe Flash Player installed.</p>
        </span>
      </span>
      <div><button class="show_settings" onclick="microphonePermission()">Microphone permission</button></div>
      <div id="status">
       Recorder Status...
      </div>
      <div>Duration: <span id="duration"></span></div>
      <div>Activity Level: <span id="activity_level"></span></div>
      <div>Upload status: <span id="upload_status"></span></div>
    </div>

    <form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="upload.php">
      <input name="authenticity_token" value="xxxxx" type="hidden">
      <input name="upload_file[parent_id]" value="1" type="hidden">
      <input name="format" value="json" type="hidden">
    </form>

    <h4>Configure Microphone</h4>
    <form class="mic_config" onsubmit="return false;">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label for="rate">Rate</label>
          <select id="rate" name="rate">
            <option value="44" selected>44,100 Hz</option>
            <option value="22">22,050 Hz</option>
            <option value="11">11,025 Hz</option>
            <option value="8">8,000 Hz</option>
            <option value="5">5,512 Hz</option>
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="gain">Gain</label>
          <select id="gain" name="gain">
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="silenceLevel">Silence Level</label>
          <select id="silenceLevel" name="silenceLevel">
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="silenceTimeout">Silence Timeout</label>
          <input id="silenceTimeout" name="silenceTimeout" value="2000"/>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input id="useEchoSuppression" name="useEchoSuppression" type="checkbox"/>
          <label for="useEchoSuppression">Use Echo Suppression</label>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input id="loopBack" name="loopBack" type="checkbox"/>
          <label for="loopBack">Loop Back</label>
        </li>

        <li>
          <button onclick="configureMicrophone();">Configure</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Database table "recordings" SQL structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE `recordings` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `upload_file` longblob NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `currenttime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

config.php

```
    <?php
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database','root','');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

upload.php

```
    <?php
$save_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . "/speaking_audios";
if(! file_exists($save_folder)) {
  if(! mkdir($save_folder)) {
    die("failed to create save folder $save_folder");
  }
 }

function valid_wav_file($file) {
  $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
  $header = fread($handle, 4);
  list($chunk_size) = array_values(unpack('V', fread($handle, 4)));
  $format = fread($handle, 4);
  fclose($handle);
  return $header == 'RIFF' && $format == 'WAVE' && $chunk_size == (filesize($file) - 8);
}

$key = 'filename';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
$upload_name = md5(uniqid() .rand()). ".wav";
#$_FILES["upload_file"]["name"][$key];
$type = $_FILES["upload_file"]["type"][$key];
$filename = "$save_folder/$upload_name";
#$filename = "$save_folder/$upload_name";
$saved = 0;
if($type == 'audio/wav' && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.wav$/', $upload_name) && valid_wav_file($tmp_name)) {
  $saved = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filename) ? 1 : 0;
}

if($_POST['format'] == 'json') {
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  print "{\"saved\": $saved}";
} else {
  print $saved ? "Saved" : 'Not saved';
}

exit;

# Save a few info to database
include "config.php";

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `recordings` (username, filename, currenttime) VALUES (:username, :filename, NOW())");
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':filename' => $upload_name));

?>
```

Well, I just want you to concentrate on the upload.php file and see what I'm doing wrong. I don't know if the problem is caused by the line "exit;" in the upload.php file. The file is being saved to the subfolder "/speaking_audios", but not to the database. Why? Maybe the problem is in the upload.php file lines:

```
include "config.php";

$upload_file=$upload_name; # also $upload_name
$username_id = $_SESSION['username'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `recordings` (username, filename, currenttime) VALUES (:username_id, :upload_file, NOW())");
$stmt->execute(array(':username_id' => $username_id, ':upload_file' => $upload_file));
```

There is also the main audio controller in javascript:

js/main.js

```
 $(function () {
  var $uploadStatus = $('#upload_status'),
    $showLevelButton = $('.show_level'),
    $hideLevelButton = $('.hide_level'),
    $level = $('.control_panel .level');

  var CLASS_CONTROLS = "control_panel";
  var CLASS_RECORDING = "recording";
  var CLASS_PLAYBACK_READY = "playback_ready";
  var CLASS_PLAYING = "playing";
  var CLASS_PLAYBACK_PAUSED = "playback_paused";

//  Embedding flash object ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  setUpFormOptions();
  var appWidth = 24;
  var appHeight = 24;
  var flashvars = {'upload_image': 'images/upload.png'};
  var params = {};
  var attributes = {'id': "recorderApp", 'name': "recorderApp"};
  swfobject.embedSWF("recorder.swf", "flashcontent", appWidth, appHeight, "11.0.0", "", flashvars, params, attributes);

//  Handling FWR events ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  window.fwr_event_handler = function fwr_event_handler() {
    $('#status').text("Last recorder event: " + arguments[0]);
    var name, $controls;
    switch (arguments[0]) {
      case "ready":
        var width = parseInt(arguments[1]);
        var height = parseInt(arguments[2]);
        FWRecorder.uploadFormId = "#uploadForm";
        FWRecorder.uploadFieldName = "upload_file[filename]";
        FWRecorder.connect("recorderApp", 0);
        FWRecorder.recorderOriginalWidth = width;
        FWRecorder.recorderOriginalHeight = height;
        $('.save_button').css({'width': width, 'height': height});
        break;

      case "no_microphone_found":
        break;

      case "microphone_user_request":
        recorderEl().addClass("floating");
        FWRecorder.showPermissionWindow();
        break;

      case "microphone_connected":
        FWRecorder.isReady = true;
        $uploadStatus.css({'color': '#000'});
        break;

      case "permission_panel_closed":
        FWRecorder.defaultSize();
        recorderEl().removeClass("floating");
        break;

      case "microphone_activity":
        $('#activity_level').text(arguments[1]);
        break;

      case "recording":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        FWRecorder.hide();
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_RECORDING);
        break;

      case "recording_stopped":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        var duration = arguments[2];
        FWRecorder.show();
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYBACK_READY);
        $('#duration').text(duration.toFixed(4) + " seconds");
        break;

      case "microphone_level":
        $level.css({width: arguments[1] * 50 + '%'});
        break;

      case "observing_level":
        $showLevelButton.hide();
        $hideLevelButton.show();
        break;

      case "observing_level_stopped":
        $showLevelButton.show();
        $hideLevelButton.hide();
        $level.css({width: 0});
        break;

      case "playing":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYING);
        break;

      case "playback_started":
        name = arguments[1];
        var latency = arguments[2];
        break;

      case "stopped":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYBACK_READY);
        break;

      case "playing_paused":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYBACK_PAUSED);
        break;

      case "save_pressed":
        FWRecorder.updateForm();
        break;

      case "saving":
        name = arguments[1];
        break;

      case "saved":
        name = arguments[1];
        var data = $.parseJSON(arguments[2]);
        if (data.saved) {
          $('#upload_status').css({'color': '#0F0'}).text(name + " was saved");
        } else {
          $('#upload_status').css({'color': '#F00'}).text(name + " was not saved");
        }
        break;

      case "save_failed":
        name = arguments[1];
        var errorMessage = arguments[2];
        $uploadStatus.css({'color': '#F00'}).text(name + " failed: " + errorMessage);
        break;

      case "save_progress":
        name = arguments[1];
        var bytesLoaded = arguments[2];
        var bytesTotal = arguments[3];
        $uploadStatus.css({'color': '#000'}).text(name + " progress: " + bytesLoaded + " / " + bytesTotal);
        break;
    }
  };

//  Helper functions ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  function setUpFormOptions() {
    var gain = $('#gain')[0];
    var silenceLevel = $('#silenceLevel')[0];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      gain.options[gain.options.length] = new Option(100 - i);
      silenceLevel.options[silenceLevel.options.length] = new Option(i);
    }
  }

  function setControlsClass($controls, className) {
    $controls.attr('class', CLASS_CONTROLS + ' ' + className);
  }

  function controlsEl(name) {
    return $('#recorder-' + name);
  }

  function recorderEl() {
    return $('#recorderApp');
  }


//  Button actions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  window.microphonePermission = function () {
    recorderEl().addClass("floating");
    FWRecorder.showPermissionWindow({permanent: true});
  };

  window.configureMicrophone = function () {
    if (!FWRecorder.isReady) {
      return;
    }
    FWRecorder.configure($('#rate').val(), $('#gain').val(), $('#silenceLevel').val(), $('#silenceTimeout').val());
    FWRecorder.setUseEchoSuppression($('#useEchoSuppression').is(":checked"));
    FWRecorder.setLoopBack($('#loopBack').is(":checked"));
  };

});
```

When the file is saved, a green message shows after the upload status in recorder.php. That is when clicking on the arrow to save/upload the upload.php comes into action, but is not shown. the user so to speak remains on the page recorder.php.

Comment: `I don't know if the problem is caused by the line "exit;"`. This question should be closed as off topic and deleted so it wont attract visitors from Google who will only find irrelevant comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know where the problem is. It's just to use:

```
if(isset($_FILES['upload_file'])){
```

before $stmt. Simple as that... Solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

Anything after the exit will not be executed!

just try removing it...

Also after your query try adding :

```
if($stmt->errorCode() == 0) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    $errors = $stmt->errorInfo();
    print_r($errors);
}
```

It may give some explanation.

Also id put my db execute before the line:

```
if($_POST['format'] == 'json') {
```

Also just noticed all your table fields are set to NOT NULL, but you only insert 3 fields. This would cause a error if they are left blank.

Your username_id field is set to int and I think you maybe your trying to populate it with username which maybe a varchar

Comment: I did it. The same thing. Nothing happened.

Comment: Nothing solved. I also added the javascript file main.js above just so you know how this audio recorder more or less works. This is the link to the complete flash file: https://github.com/michalstocki/FlashWavRecorder.

Comment: Updated original answer - check your recordings table